# How can I revert a chmod -R +x on the etc directory?

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and I messed up with the `chmod -R` command!

I mistyped the directory while running chmod
and instead of `chmod -R +x ./etc` I wrote `chmod -R +x /etc`.

So now everything in /etc and every subfolder and file has +x permission.

I was able to fix the SSH connection to the server by removing x permissions from /etc/ssh, and so far other services seem to be running fine, but sooner or later some other service will fail because of this, and I want to prevent that. Any idea what to do to fix it soon as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the *best* way to deal with permission problems is to reinstall from a backup.

At a minimum, without a backup we can probably only make a best guess at what files should have which permissions.

That being said, after probing my system, I think I've found a pretty good best guess you can use for a start.

Consider making a backup of the current /etc with its current permissions in case this goes badly.

`sudo cp -R /etc /etc.bak`

First I'm going to get a list of all files under /etc

`sudo find /etc -type f > allfiles.txt`

My best guess: anything with a "shebang" is an executable script, and should remain executable

`sudo find /etc -type f -exec grep --files-with-matches --binary-files=without-match '#!' {} + > shebang.txt`

Now then, I need to find the list of files that are in /etc but don't contain a shebang. We can do this by running

`cat allfiles.txt shebang.txt | sort | uniq -u > nonexecutable.txt`

At this point do a sanity check and see how many lines are in each file.

`wc -l *.txt`

In my case, I have a list of about 4000 files in etc, about 125 contain shebangs, and about 3900 files in nonexecutable.txt

If you're happy with the counts (hard to tell without a backup to compare to) you can finally modify all nonexecutable files to remove the executable bit.

`cat allfiles.txt shebang.txt | sort | uniq -u | xargs -n1 chmod -x`

xargs takes our list of nonexecutable files, breaks them out one-by-one (with the `-n1` flag), and passes each one to the command `chmod -x`

---

Known problems:

1.
I had one executable in /etc that wasn't caught by this method. For some reason there's an executable of resolved in my /etc that doesn't contain a shebang.

The command to fix this, after running everything else, is

`find /etc -iname 'resolved' -exec chmod +x {} +`

But I have no way to tell what other executables you might have had prior to the permission change.

2.
I don't know how to fix directory permissions. Some directories aren't world readable, and shouldn't have the executable bit. *Hopefully* the sensitive files underneath those directories have read permissions disabled.

3.
Binary executables won't be caught with the shebang search. I don't see any binary executables in my /etc directory, so this is probably low risk.

4.
A couple of files with shebangs on my system are not executable. This includes a couple of ufw .init scripts.

---

Here's an overview of some files that I found are executable. I think these were all found when looking for the shebang.

- All files under /etc/init.d
- All files under /etc/kernel
- All files under /etc/update-motd.d
- All files under /etc/pm/sleep.d
- Most files under /etc/grub.d (except README)
- Most files under /etc/cron.* (except the cron.d directory)
- /etc/console-setup/*.sh
- /etc/X11/Xsession
- /etc/X11/Xreset

Answer (score 1):

If a backup (or snapshot) is available, I'd restore from those.
If for any reason a checkpoint is not available, then you can try the following

```
$ aptitude --reinstall install '~i'
```

This will reinstall packages already installed and reset their permissions to default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to revert `chmod` or for argument's sake, any other command as there is no record kept of everything that was done. The best that one could do would be to `strace the chmod command and append it to a file and look for the previous and current mode of every directory, file, and whatever else was impacted by the command but there are probably around seven people in the world who would want to go through that kind of tedium.

The best thing to do in this case would be to restore from a backup and that's assuming one exists. In the case that one doesn't, it's best to just reinstall the OS. One could copy everything from a live CD or live USB but that would only impact what was on the aforementioned media and wouldn't account for changes that were made since installation. It is possible to research the permissions of everything that exists and set them to what they normally are but it would take far less time to just reinstall the OS and the other software that has data in `/etc` than to do the former. Any other method would require a lot of guesswork which isn't viable for the reasons that I've given.

Answer (score -3):

if the server is not a public server, I think it is better to copy your data "backup" and reinstall Ubuntu. otherwise you can try to correct the permission with some commands. but I will never be like before.
the root user should be the owner of the data and since it is known to all that most files on a server should have permission 644 and directories should have permission 755, i suggest the following as discussed in the ubuntu wiki:

```
$ sudo su
______________
chown -R root:root /etc    # this will chnage the owner to root
__________________
find /etc -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +    # this will search all exec files and change the permisson to 644

______________________
find /etc -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +      # this will search all exec dirs and change the permisson to 755
__________________
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/* /etc/rc.local /etc/network/* /etc/cron.*/*
_____________________
chmod 400 /etc/ssh/ssh*key
```

Comment: There are a few commercial projects that I'm hosting for other people, so at this moment I'm trying to fix it just by comparing and manually changing file permissions with ones that another VM with the ubuntu distro has. The ownership of the files should be good, all I changed was the execute(+X) permission.

Comment: Changing read/write permissions is a terrible idea for security. Instead of forcing modes 644, 755, and 400, you should touch _ONLY_ the executable bit. The command to remove execute from all files but leave execute on directories is `chmod -R -x+X /etc` but even so I can't generally predict which files are supposed to be executable. init.d, rc.local, and cron.* are only a start on my system.

Comment: Most files/directories under `/etc` are owned by `root:root` but not all so a blanket `chown` is not a good idea, especially since the OP's command did not change ownership. I also wonder where you get the idea that most files on a server are perm `0644` and directories are `0755`. This is *not* the case on the systems I'm familiar with.